# string_agg ignore specific value in column

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
 SELECT string_agg(col, ',') as cols
        FROM (
            SELECT
            json_field_name || ' AS ' || csv_field_name as col
            FROM pricing.sandbox_configurations
            WHERE include is true
            ORDER BY sequence_id
) a
```

Doing so gives me a result like

```
product_cd AS product_cd,product_name AS product_name
```

However, what if I wanted to ignore the value name product_name and just want to return rest of the column values as strin glike that.

How would I achieve that?

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore `product_name` by removing riws with this value in where clause.

```
SELECT string_agg(col, ',') as cols
            FROM (
                SELECT
                json_field_name || ' AS ' || csv_field_name as col
                FROM pricing.sandbox_configurations
                WHERE include is true
                and  <>'product_name'
                ORDER BY sequence_id
    ) a
```